# My app crashes after multiple rotates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, autorotate, memory-leaks

My app is crashing when I try and rotate it more than a couple of times. I first thought it was just the iPhone Simulator, so I loaded the app onto an iPod touch, and it crashed after fewer rotates in a row. I suspect it's a memory leak in one of my rotate methods. The only place I can think that the crash is being caused is in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`. The only two methods related to rotate that I've added/extended are `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` and `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration` and I don't think it's the first because it only contains the two words: `return YES;`. Here is my `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method so you can review it and see where the possible memory leak is.

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
{
 UIFont *theFont;


 if ((orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
 {
  theFont = [yearByYear.font fontWithSize:16.0];
  yearByYear.font = theFont;
  [theview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(460.0f, 635.0f)];
 }
 else
 {
  theFont = [yearByYear.font fontWithSize:10.0];
  yearByYear.font = theFont;
  [theview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300.0f, 460.0f)];
 }

 [theFont release];
}
```

yearByYear is a `UITextView` and theview is a `UIScrollView`.

Comment: Crashes like this are usually over-releasing objects, not leaks.  Leaks take a long time to fill memory (unless its a flood) and you would get a memory warning first.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be releasing `theFont`. You don't own the object.

You can also simplify what you're doing to:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration  {

   if ((orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
      yearByYear.font = [yearByYear.font fontWithSize:16.0]
      [theview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(460.0f, 635.0f)];
   }
   else
   {
      yearByYear.font = [yearByYear.font fontWithSize:10.0]
      [theview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300.0f, 460.0f)];
   }
}
```

Getting rid of `theFont` completely.

Comment: Yes. To just to be super clear, according to the Cocoa memory guidelines (don't have link handy, you should Google for it), since you're not explicitly `alloc`ing or `new`ing or `copy`ing the font, you shouldn't release it (unless you retain it yourself first).

Comment: Note that yearByYear *should* be retaining and releasing the font appropriately in its setter method. This will be done for you if the method is synthesized and has the right property attributes...